# Excel locks my own files

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created an Excel spreadsheet and saved it as "file.xlsx". I have shut down my computer and turned in on again. I have tried to open the Excel spreadsheet file. I get the message, that the file is locked by My Own Username and can only be opened with write protection (I get messages in German, the exact English message text may differ). After a few seconds, Excel tells me that the file is now available, but when I click to edit, it closes and reopens the file and again shows the message that the file is locked and write protected.

The problem is caused by a file in the same directory. It is created by Excel. The name of that file is "~$file.xlsx" and it is listed when I look in the directory in terminal using `ls -a`. I know that this file is the problem, because when I delete it using `rm -r "~\$file.xlsx"` (with backslash to escape the dollar sign) the spreadsheed file "file.xlsx" opens fine. But when I change, save, and close the file, then shut down my computer, turn it on again and attempt to re-open the Excel spreadsheet file, it is locked again and there is another "~$file.xlsx" in the directory.

How can I keep Excel from locking my own file?

This is Excel for Mac 2011, I'm on OS 10.9.5. The file is not used by anyone else, nor from myself from another computer. No other Microsoft software has similar problems, and Word for example doesn't create "~$file.docx" files (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Which OS version do you use? Do you have any backup / sync tool that might access those files? Do you have similar issue with other programs (e.g. Word, Power Point)? If not, then do they not create the same backup files, or just work without displaying the message?

Comment: @MátéJuhász I have edited the information into my question (at the end).

Comment: The creation of that ~$-file is normal behavior, but when you close your file, it should go away. My guess would be that Excel has an issue when closing (and never finishes), or Excel is not allowed to remove that file (authorizations?)